# Write a pseudo code for the puzzle

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Given the waste at certain positions with values between 1.01 and 3.00 and you can carry atmost 3.00kg at one time. How many minimum number of bags required to carry the waste?

Input

```
4
1.30 1.40 1.50 1.60
```

Output

```
2
```

Input

```
4
1.40 1.70 1.50 1.50
```

Output

```
3
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an assignment rather than a question.

Comment: See 'knapsack' algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pseudo code would be like this

```
double sum=0,max=3.00;

int count=1;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){

    sum+=array[i];

    if(sum>max){

        count++;

        sum-=max;

    }

}

print(count);
```